# How do I remove all instances of an element that appear in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The code I have right now, removes most of the instances, however it does not remove all of them. What am I doing wrong?

```js
let nums = [1, 90, 90, 1123, 90, 4534, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90];

function removeAll(array, item) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === item) {
      array.splice(array.indexOf(item), 1);
    }
  }
  return array;
}
    
console.log(removeAll(nums, 90));
```

Comment: Why don't you use `filter` for this?

Comment: `array.splice` will change the array use `array.filter` instead

Comment: You are removing elements from the array while looping it. That is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let nums = [1, 90, 90, 1123, 90, 4534, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90];

function removeAll(array, item) {
  return array.filter(function(value) {
    return value !== item;
  });
}

console.log(removeAll(nums, 90));
```